# Prob. 10, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: If $f(x)\to 0$, $g(x)\to 0$, $f^\prime(x)\to A$, $g^\prime(x)\to B$ as $x\to 0$, and $B\neq 0$, then $f(x)/g(x)\to$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Here is Prob. 10, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are complex differentiable functions on $(0, 1)$, $f(x) \to 0$, $g(x) \to 0$, $f^\prime(x) \to A$, $g^\prime(x) \to B$ as $x \to 0$, where $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers, $B \neq 0$. Prove that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } = \frac{A}{B}. $$
>   Compare with Example 5.18. *Hint:* 
>   $$ \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } = \left\{ \frac{ f(x) }{x} - A \right\} \cdot \frac{x}{ g(x) } + A \cdot \frac{ x }{ g(x) }. $$
>   Apply Theorem 5.13 to the real and imaginary parts of $f(x)/x$ and $g(x)/x$.

Now here is Theorem 5.13:

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are real and differentiable in $(a, b)$, and $g^\prime(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$, where $-\infty \leq a < b \leq +\infty$. Suppose 
>   $$ \frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)} \to A \ \mbox{ as } \ x \to a. \tag{13} $$
>   If 
>   $$ f(x) \to 0 \ \mbox{ and } \ g(x) \to 0 \ \mbox{ as } \ x \to a, \tag{14} $$
>   or if 
>   $$ g(x) \to +\infty \ \mbox{ as } \ x \to a, \tag{15} $$
>   then 
>   $$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to A \ \mbox{ as } \ x \to a. \tag{16}$$
>   The analogous statement is of course also true if $x \to b$, or if $g(x) \to -\infty$ in (15). Let us note that we now use the limit concept in the extended sense of Definition 4.33.

Here is Definition 4.33:

> Let $f$ be a real function defined on $E \subset \mathbb{R}$. We say that 
>   $$ f(t) \to A \ \mbox{ as } \ t \to x, $$
>   where $A$ and $x$ are in the extended real number system, if for every neighborhood $U$ of $A$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V \cap E$ is not empty, and such that $f(t) \in U$ for all $t \in V \cap E$, $t \neq x$.

My effort:

> By Theorem 5.13, we note that 
>   $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Re f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Re f^\prime(x)}{1} = \Re A, $$
>   $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Re g(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Re g^\prime(x)}{1} = \Re B, $$
>   $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Im f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Im f^\prime(x)}{1} = \Im A, $$
>   and
>   $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Im  g(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Im  g^\prime(x)}{1} = \Im B. $$
>   So 
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ f(x) }{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Re f(x) + \iota \Im f(x) }{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\Re f(x) }{x} + \iota \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\Im f(x) }{x} = \Re A + \iota \Im A = A,$$
>   and 
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ g(x) }{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \Re g(x) + \iota \Im g(x) }{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\Re g(x) }{x} + \iota \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\Im g(x) }{x} = \Re B + \iota \Im B = B.$$
>   Since $B \neq 0$, therefore 
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ x }{g(x)} = \frac{1}{B},$$
>   and so 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } &= \lim_{x\to 0} \left[ \left\{ \frac{ f(x) }{x} - A \right\} \cdot \frac{x}{ g(x) } + A \cdot \frac{ x }{ g(x) } \right] \\
> &= \lim_{x\to 0} \left\{ \left( \frac{ f(x) }{x} - A \right)  \frac{x}{ g(x) } \right\} \ + \  \lim_{x\to 0} \left( A \cdot \frac{ x }{ g(x) } \right) \\
> &= \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{ f(x) }{x} - A \right)  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{g(x)} \ + \ A \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ x }{ g(x) } \\
> &= 0 \cdot \frac{1}{B} + A \frac{1}{B} \\
> &= \frac{A}{B}.
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   In the above chain we have been able to split the limit into a sum and then into a product because all the limits involved exist.

Is my reasoning correct and rigorous enough for Rudin? If so, then is my presentation good enough as well? Have I used Rudin's hint correctly?

If not, then what is wanting in my attempt?

Comment: I am also studying Rudin and this is pretty much what I did, so either we're both good or we both goofed.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I can't see nothing wrong with your reasoning!

The main deal (and why we use the somewhat crazy hint) is that it's quite difficult to split $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ into real and imaginary parts directly; besides, if $B\neq 0$, its (for example) real part may as well be $0$.